# Python3 reduce function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dict/JSON that I use in JS that has duplicate items:

```
{
  0:{
    "id" : 1,
    "name": "test"
  },
  1:{
    "id" : 2,
    "name": "other name"
  },
  2:{
    "id" : 1,
    "name": "does not have to be the same name"
  },{
    "id" : 3,
    "name": "but they could be the same"
  },
  3:{
    "id" : 2,
    "name": "other name"
  }
}
```

And I want to reduce it to:

```
{
  0:{
    "id" : 1,
    "name": "test"
  },
  1:{
    "id" : 2,
    "name": "other name"
  },
  2:{
    "id" : 3,
    "name": "but they could be the same"
  }
}
```

The criteria being that the id has to be unique, no matter if the rest of the item is different.

With JS I used the following code:

```
const data = [ { "id" : 1, "name": "test" }, { "id" : 2, "name": "other name" }, { "id" : 1, "name": "does not have to be the same name" },{ "id" : 3, "name": "but they could be the same" },{ "id" : 2, "name": "other name" }, ],
      unique = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.id] = r[o.id] || o;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(unique);
```

However, I can't seem to do the same with python3.9. I found the `functools.reduce()` function and I tried using it with lambas, but dics are different from JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using the following code:

```
data = [i for n, i in enumerate(data) if i['id'] not in {d['id'] for j,d in enumerate(data[n+1:])}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, the input you gave is invalid JSON.
According to your JS, the structure should be like this.

```
foo = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name": "other name"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "does not have to be the same name"
    },
    {
         "id" : 3,
         "name": "but they could be the same"
    },
    {
         "id" : 2,
         "name": "other name"
    }
]
```

That being said, if you want a solution using `reduce`, something like this would work.

```
from functools import reduce
foo = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name": "other name"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "does not have to be the same name"
    },
    {
         "id" : 3,
         "name": "but they could be the same"
    },
    {
         "id" : 2,
         "name": "other name"
    }
]
# in my opinion, the readability suffers here
# sometimes you need to be ok with using more than one line
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y] if not any(i['id'] == y['id'] for i in x) else x, foo, [])
print(result)
```

A bit more readable example would be to use an actual function rather than a `lambda`.

```
from functools import reduce
foo = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name": "other name"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "does not have to be the same name"
    },
    {
         "id" : 3,
         "name": "but they could be the same"
    },
    {
         "id" : 2,
         "name": "other name"
    }
]
def build_list(result_list, list_element):
    if not any(list_element['id'] == i['id'] for i in result_list):
        return result_list + [list_element]
    return result_list

result = reduce(build_list, foo, [])
print(result)
```

But this is still not the style I would write it in.
For me personally I would track duplicates with a `set` and avoid a comprehension / `reduce` altogether.

```
foo = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name": "other name"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "does not have to be the same name"
    },
    {
         "id" : 3,
         "name": "but they could be the same"
    },
    {
         "id" : 2,
         "name": "other name"
    }
]
result = []
ids = set()
for dct in foo:
    if not dct['id'] in ids:
        ids.add(dct['id'])
        result.append(dct)
print(result)
```